# I don't know how to verify if the phone number already exist. I'm just a newbie and i don't know what to do now

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I an newbie to android studio and sq lite database, i am developing a login page for an application like the login in gmail. Here i am taking user phone number as primary key.when the user enter his phone number it will redirect to password screen if already exist. I don't know how to checked whether the phone number is already exist or not. 
This my code.

PhoneNumber.java

```
    package com.hernaezchristophergmail.projectitrack;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;




    public class PhoneNumber extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText Pnum;
        Button Con;
        UserDBHelper userDBHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
        Context context = this;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_number);

            Pnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tbPnumber);
            Con = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btbCon);

            Con.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override

                    public void onClick(View v){
                    String pnumber = Pnum.getText().toString().trim();



                    String storedPassword = UserDBHelper.getSingleEntry(pnumber,sqLiteDatabase);
                  /*  if(pnumber.equals("")||pnumber1.equals("")){
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneNumber.this, "Please", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }*/

                    if(!pnumber.equals(storedPassword)){
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneNumber.this, "Invalid Login details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    else{
                        Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneNumber.this,PasswordScreen.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

       /* public void add(View view){
            String pnumber = Pnum.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneNumber.this, PasswordScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        */

        public void create(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneNumber.this, SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed(){

        }
    }
```

UserDBHelper.java

```
    package com.hernaezchristophergmail.projectitrack;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * Created by Christopher on 4/26/2016.
     */
    public class UserDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ITRACK_USER.DB";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


        private static final String CREATEINFO_QUERY=
                "CREATE TABLE "+ UserContact.UserInformation.TABLE_NAME+"("+ UserContact.UserInformation.User_Password+" TEXT," +
                        UserContact.UserInformation.User_PhoneNumber+" TEXT," + UserContact.UserInformation.User_Firstame+" TEXT," + UserContact.UserInformation.User_LastName+" TEXT);";

        public UserDBHelper(Context context){

            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
            Log.e("DATABASE OPERATIONS","DATABASE CREATED / OPENED ...");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATEINFO_QUERY);
            Log.e("DATABASE OPERATION", "TABLE CREATED ...");

        }


        public void saveInfo(String first,String last,String pnum, String pass, SQLiteDatabase db){
            ContentValues contentvalues = new ContentValues();
            contentvalues.put(UserContact.UserInformation.User_Firstame,first);
            contentvalues.put(UserContact.UserInformation.User_LastName,last);
            contentvalues.put(UserContact.UserInformation.User_PhoneNumber,pnum);
            contentvalues.put(UserContact.UserInformation.User_Password,pass);

            db.insert(UserContact.UserInformation.TABLE_NAME, null, contentvalues);
            Log.e ("Database Operation", "one row inserted . . .");
        }

        public static String getSingleEntry(String pnum, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(UserContact.UserInformation.TABLE_NAME, null, " User_PhoneNumber=?",
                    new String[] { pnum }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String phonenum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
            cursor.close();
            return phonenum;
        }


        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }
```

UserContact.java

```
public class UserContact {

    public static abstract class UserInformation{
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "info";
        public static final String User_Password= "password";
        public static final String User_LastName = "last_name";
        public static final String User_Firstame = "first_name";
        public static final String User_PhoneNumber = "phone_number";
        public static final String PHOTOID = "photo_id";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the Error?
Also, please look into this.

```
public static String getSingleEntry(String pnum, SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
            Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(UserContact.UserInformation.TABLE_NAME, null, " User_PhoneNumber=?",
                    new String[] { pnum }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.getCount() < 1) {
                cursor.close();
                return "NOT EXIST";
            }
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String phonenum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
            cursor.close();
            return phonenum; //RETURN YES / NO if exist not the actual password for security purpose.
        }
```

---

```
if(!pnumber.equals(storedPassword)){ //ALSO HERE, return YES/NO if exist or new, not the actual password.
                        Toast.makeText(PhoneNumber.this, "Invalid Login details", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        return;
                    }
```

Comment: i still dont get it.

Comment: i still can't go to the next screen

Comment: can you share the error? make sure that your queries to the database are successfully sent to the DB.

Comment: Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(UserContact.UserInformation.TABLE_NAME, null, " User_PhoneNumber=?",

Comment: String storedPassword = UserDBHelper.getSingleEntry(pnumber,sqLiteDatabase);

Comment: im still getting the same error all over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Errors in query 
**1. Wrong column name** `User_PhoneNumber` never exists in your table. Write query as below

```
 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(UserContact.UserInformation.TABLE_NAME, null, UserContact.UserInformation.User_PhoneNumber+"=?",
                    new String[] { pnum }, null, null, null);
```

and
**2. Wrong column name :)** you are reading password instead of phone number.. write

```
String phonenum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserContact.UserInformation.User_PhoneNumber));
```

instead of

```
String phonenum = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("password"));
```

Comment: im still getting the same error.. you think my PhoneNumber. java is correct?

Comment: check what value you are getting for this object `phonenum`

Answer (score 0):

The below method will return the name for the given number. By this way you can trigger whether the number is available or not. Returns true if the number is there else false.

```
public Boolean numberExists(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
        String contactName = null;
        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
        try {

            if (cursor != null) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @chrys:: This is a separate method, you can put this in your code snippet and send the number for which you had to check the availability.